# Modify redis.Cmder content in hook

Tags: redis, hook, go-redis

I want to add some prefix on `redis` keys in `BeforeProcessFunc` hook before access, but I find there is no way to modify `redis.Cmder`? How to do it?

I try to use (https://goplay.tools/snippet/rIpK1R2mYA1)
but get a `panic` error:

`panic:reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on slice Value`